# Angular 2 - ngSwitchCase - Correct Syntax (Wrapper)

Tags: html, angular, wrapper

Im currently working on a leaderboard demo where a player has a number of games, points and a ratio of points/games. On top of my leaderboards I want a line which shows what is beneath.

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<ul class="leaderboard">
    <li>
        <span class="badge">Rank</span> Name
        <div class="wrapper"[ngSwitch]="type">
            <span *ngSwitchCase="'games'" class="points">Games</span>
            <span *ngSwitchCase="'points'" class="points">Points</span>
            <span *ngSwitchCase="'ratio'" class="points">Ratio</span>
            <div class="wrapper" *ngSwitchDefault>
                <span class="points">Ratio</span>
                <span class="points">Points</span>
                <span class="points">Games</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I think the second div with ngSwitchDefault is the Problem. But I am relatively new to Angular 2 and its usage with html. How can i deal with that in one html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plunker with switch working, the single quotes are ok (my bad).

`enter code here`

https://plnkr.co/edit/1FWbbWiLX1EGsm6Pe9YA?p=preview

Comment: I changes this but it is still only showing Rank and Games

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/rmakH43HkHaDTaPAUVCJ/ this is not everything only the part about because I dont know how to upload my whole project